# .htaccess redirect from non-existing URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Somehow I can't find a solution to the problem.

I need to have any URL for /blog/pro/* to be redirected to /blog/ (not /blog/*) where * is any directory, while /blog/pro/ actually exists but there're no sub-directories in it.

I believe, it should be

```
Redirect 301 ^blog/pro/(.*?)/ /blog
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` doesn't support regex and you need to match leading `/`.

So you need to have this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/pro/(.*)/ /blog/
```